# How to Use Methods of a Class for a Private Member Object of Another Class

Tags: java, class

I am creating a class which has as one of its private members an object of another class. When I try to call the public instance methods of the class that is already created in my public instance methods, I get a NullPointerException.

I tested it and when I call the find function from the constructor, it works fine, but when I call the find function from the next random function, it gives me the exception. What is happening?

```
public class Percolation
{
   private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
   private boolean sites[][];

   public Percolation(int N)//constructor
   {
       sites = new boolean[N][N];
       int arraySize = N * N;
       WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(arraySize);
       System.out.println("we found the first node at " + uf.find(31));
   }

   public void trialQuickFind()
   {
       System.out.println("we found the first node at " + uf.find(31));
   }
}
```

Comment: show your code where you have instance

Comment: It just means that the variable is null, so make sure you aren't setting it to null where you shouldn't be, and also ensure the variable is not null when using it.

Answer (score 8):

In the constructor you **shadow** `uf`. Change

```
WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(arraySize);
```

to

```
this.uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(arraySize);
```

The Wikipedia entry on [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) says (in part),

> In computer programming, **variable shadowing** occurs when a variable declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope. At the level of identifiers (names, rather than variables), this is known as name masking. This outer variable is said to be shadowed by the inner variable, while the inner identifier is said to mask the outer identifier.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared a new local variable

```
 WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(arraySize);
```

which is different from your global variable

```
private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
```

it is best to practice encapsulation or the use of setters and getters to avoid this problem

```
public class Percolation
{
   private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
   private boolean sites[][];

   public Percolation(int N)//constructor
   {
       sites = new boolean[N][N];
       int arraySize = N * N;
       setWeigntedQuickUnionUf( new WeightedQuickUnionUF(arraySize));
       System.out.println("we found the first node at " + uf.find(31));
   }

   public void trialQuickFind()
   {
       System.out.println("we found the first node at " +getWeigntedQuickUnionUf().find(31));
   }
   private void  setWeigntedQuickUnionUf(WeightedQuickUnionUF uf){
         this.uf=uf;
}

   private WeightedQuickUnionUF  getWeigntedQuickUnionUf( ){
         return this.uf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For encapsulation and abstraction purposes:

Create an interface, say:

```
    public interface UfListener {
        getUf();
    }
```

`WeightedQuickUnionUF` should `implements UfListener` then pass it the uf reading.

Then, give `Percolation` and instance of UfListener, and call it:

`uf = ufListener.getUf();`